# how to use different colors for parts of option text in html select?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to dislay different parts of the option text in select using different colors?

```
<select name="cards">
  <option value="0">This is green This is black</option>
  <option value="1">This is green This is black</option>
</select>
```

How to do it? Is it possible to do it with css or javascript? Maybe there some libraries that allow to do it?
Is it possible at all?

Comment: any reason not to use span tags?

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: `span` is illegal in the `option` tag

Answer (score -3):

Hope this will help you.

```
    <select name="select">
    <option value="1" style="color:blue">Test</option>
    <option value="2" style="color:green">Test</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: OP is very clear that he need different colors for parts of the option text not for each option.

Comment: I meant that in each option part of the text should have one color and part of the text another color.

Comment: Guess what your [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/3x55Lrg5/) not even works.